# Jquery conditional ajax query not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a list of `li`s, and on `mousemove`, the code checks if a certain `div` doesn't contain a certain class. If it is the case, the ajax query is launched. Unfortunately it's not working and I do not understand why as my code is working if I do not use ajax. Thank you in advance for your help.

My HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="contentWrapper">
            <div id="contentOne" class="content">
                <ul>
                    <li refSortie="mmm">mmm</li>
                    <li refSortie="sss">sss</li>
                    <li refSortie="mmm">mmm</li>
                    <li refSortie="mmm">mmm</li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="contentTwo" class="content"></div>
            <div id="contentThree" class="content"></div>
            <div id="contentFour" class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My JS:

```
$('#contentOne li').mousemove(function () {
    var refSortie = $(this).attr('refSortie');

    if(!$('#contentOne').hasClass('freezed')) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/test2.php',
            data: 'refSortie=' + refSortie,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#contentTwo').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}).mouseout(function () {
    if(!$('#contentOne').hasClass('freezed')) {
        $('#contentTwo').html('');
    }
});
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['refSortie'])) {
    echo $refSortie=$_POST['refSortie'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Please show the HTML for this.

Comment: It's working for me. Its a nonstop AJAX request on mousemove. Did you include the `<script>` tags and the Jquery files? What error are you getting?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? What errors are you getting? Have you debugged with the console?

Comment: Hello, thanks for helping out. Yes, I include the <script> and the Jquery files. I have no error, it is just not working. The thing is that when I am using $('#contentTwo').html(refSortie); insted of the $.ajax() it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on what you posted. Here's what I got and it's working fine for me.

### HTML & JQUERY

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="contentWrapper">
                <div id="contentOne" class="content">
                    <ul>
                        <li refSortie="mmm">mmm</li>
                        <li refSortie="sss">sss</li>
                        <li refSortie="mmm">mmm</li>
                        <li refSortie="mmm">mmm</li>
                     </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="contentTwo" class="content"></div>
                <div id="contentThree" class="content"></div>
                <div id="contentFour" class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#contentOne li').mousemove(function(){
        var refSortie=$(this).attr('refSortie');

        if(!$('#contentOne').hasClass('freezed')){

            $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'test2.php',
        data:'refSortie='+refSortie,
        success:function(data){
            $('#contentTwo').html(data);    
        }
        });}
    }).mouseout(function(){
        if(!$('#contentOne').hasClass('freezed')){
            $('#contentTwo').html('');}    
    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

### PHP

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['refSortie'])) {
        echo $refSortie=$_POST['refSortie'];
    }

?>
```

Did I do something different than you?

### Firebug Console view:

[image]

Comment: Also, are you using a debugger like firebug?

Comment: I passed your html instead of mine and still not working. When you say it is working for you, what is the behavior you are having on mousemove and mouseout?

Comment: I checked JSFiddle: Code is valid, html is valid. I downloaded FireBug but do not know what to look at. Nevertheless, can you tell what you are having as behavior when you go over a li with text written in it?

Comment: I get that value back from the php page. In FireBug view via the [console](http://getfirebug.com/logging) You'll see the value come back.

Comment: The fist info I have in the console is for test2.php saying no element found and then "Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy" (fragment.appendChild(ret[i]);

Comment: Are you using any other librarys? What browser are you using?

Comment: Only FancyBox and i tried in Chrome,FireFox and Safari. I am pretty sure the problem comes from the php file. Syntax?Or something else?

Comment: What firebug version do you use mine looks different an i cannot focus on test2.php for instance as you seem to abble to.

Comment: Interesting, I put eror_reporting(0) above <?php by mistake and now the mousemove works but returning "error_reporting(0)". So definately something wrong with the php file.But what?

Comment: Hello Monty. I reinstalled MAMP and it is finally working! Sorry for all the trouble and thank you very much for the time you dedicated to help me out.